# Add/remove playlist items in JW Player (using MySQ/RTMP)

Tags: mysql, jwplayer, playlist

Ok, we have a server with hundreds of videos (from a local tv station) and we are making a small website for the videos to be shown using RTMP and a MySQL database. All the video names are stored in the database and we use PHP to show the names in a list and make them clickable (onClick to add the video to player). I have got this working but now we would like to add a small pre-roll before every video. It's a small clip showing our logo for a few seconds.

Let's say I have a playlist like this:

1. Pre-roll video
2. Main video

Then I want to click a link (which is generated from my MySQL database) to change the second video to some other video:

1. Pre-roll video (same as before)
2. Main video (new)

And then load the playlist and play it from the beginning.
All this using RTMP.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using a PHP variable as the second video.